# How to hide/show gmaps.js markers on click of link

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to make it so you can click an external link and show a marker category when the link is clicked. I want the map to hide markers until the link is clicked, and remove the markers when another link is clicked for a different marker category.

```
map.addMarker({
    lat: 37.20162,
    lng: -112.986244,
    title: 'Zion National Park',
    icon: "../images/attractions_icon.png",

    }
  });
```

Can I just set an id for the map marker and refer to this from a link? I'm completely lost.

Here is an example, but I want it to do the opposite. I want to hide the markers until a link is clicked.

http://www.fisgonia.com/

Comment: When you say you want to hide the markers until a "link" is clicked, are you referring to the check boxes on the left side of http://www.fisgonia.com/?

Comment: Yeah I want just <a hrefs> not check boxes though

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a bunch of Markers, so you'll want to loop over some Arrays to produce your results, like:

```
//JavaScript should be external for caching - mapstuff.js    
var doc = document, gm = google.maps;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
var map = new gm.Map(E('theMap'), {/*map options*/});
function addMarker(title, icon, lat, lng) {
  return new gm.Marker({
    position: new gm.LatLng(lat, lng),
    title: title,
    icon: icon,
    map: map
  });
}
var cat1Img = '../images/attractions_icon.png';
var cat2Img = 'whatever.png';
var cat3Img = 'another.png';
//add more images as necessary 
var cat1 = [['Zion National Park', cat1Img, 37.20162, -112.986244], [/*repeat step 1 with different lat lng title using the same cat1Img*/], [/*you know the drill*/], [/*you know the drill*/]];
var cat2 = [/*same like cat1 using cat2Img*/];
var cat3 = [/*see the pattern*/];
var catComb = [cat1, cat2, cat3]; //add to as necessary
var cats = E('cats'), catAnchors = cats.childNodes;
for(var n=0,l=catAnchors.length; n<l; n++){
  var cat = catAnchors[n];
  if(cat.nodeType === 1){
    cat.onclick = function(){
      for(var i in catComb){
        for(var q in catComb[i]){
          addMarker.apply(addMarker, catComb[i][q]);
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
}

/*should be external for caching - mapstuff.css*/
body{
  margin:0;
}
#main{
  width:980px; padding:15px 20px; margin:0 auto;
}
#mapTest{
  color:#007; text-align:center; margin:10px;
}
#cats{
  width:200px; float:left:
}
#cats a{
  display:block;
}
#theMap{
  height:400px; width:740px; background:url('placeholder.png'); float:left;
}
.br{
  clear:left; /*backward compatible*/
}

<!--HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <title>Map Stuff is Cool</title>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      @import 'mapstuff.css';
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='main'>
    <h1 id='mapTest'>Map Test</div>
    <div id='cats'>
      <a href='#'>Category 1</a>
      <a href='#'>Category 2</a>
      <a href='#'>Category 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id='theMap'></div>
    <div class='br'></div>
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='mapstuff.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you send a link or two my way so I can figure it out?? Anything that leads me in the right direction

Comment: Yo, do I just keep the <a href='#'>Category 1</a> like that? I thought it needed to link to cat1 cat2 etc

Comment: I'm using `childNodes` inside the `id='cats'`, so you don't need an id just change `Category 1` ect. as needed. `#` means the current page, since the `onclick` functions return false it should disable the default behavior of reloading the page. You have to know your lat and lng for this to work. If you just have addresses you'll want to use the `google.maps.Geocoder` Constructor and its `.geocode()` method, which you will pass an object like: `{address: 'someAddress'}`. I can put a rundown in the code above, if needed.